# What exactly is groovy-sql and are there other modules like it?

Tags: sql, groovy, dependencies

It's a .jar [available in various versions at Maven Repo](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-sql).

But what category is it? It is published by org.codehaus.groovy, the same outfit that I get my groovy-all dependency from. I also find that `import groovy.sql` doesn't work in a script unless I specifically include this dependency. So it would appear not to be part of the core language.

Outside a Gradle context I find that I have to manually put the .jar file under ~/.groovy/lib in order to use it. If I put the wrong version (e.g. 2.5.9 for 3.0.2) under ~/.groovy/lib the script won't run... even if I'm not using groovy.sql at all!

Is this a "dependency"? It seems a typically powerful and hassle-free Groovy way of manipulating databases. Are there any other powerful add-on (non-core) Groovy .jar file modules like this, which have to be manually placed under ~/.groovy/lib, that I should know about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

groovy consists of subprojects:

- https://github.com/apache/groovy/tree/master/subprojects

and `groovy-sql` one of the subprojects

all subprojects are published in maven as separate libraries

prior to version `2.5` there was `groovy-all-XX.jar` that includes all other groovy libraries

- https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-all/2.4.19/

however starting from v 2.5 groovy-all represented by `groovy-all-XX.pom` that depends on all other groovy libraries

- https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-all/2.5.0/

so, to include all groovy features you have to specify `groovy-all` in your maven/gradle/... dependency

and finally useful site to dig dependencies:

- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-all/3.0.2

Comment: Thanks, very helpful. In fact I found I had the following line in build.gradle: `implementation 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:3.+'`... I just replaced this with `implementation group: 'org.codehaus.groovy', name: 'groovy-all', version: '3.0.2', ext: 'pom'`... incidentally, putting `implementation 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:3.0.2:pom'` didn't work: that mysterious `ext: 'pom'` obviously necessitates further research.

Comment: I find I **still** have to include `implementation 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-sql:3.0.2'` in build gradle, even after including the "groovy-all"-flavour general Groovy dependency. Again, much further research needed on my part before I attain enlightenment!